# SparkLauncher. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>

Tags: java, docker, apache-spark, spring-boot, yaml

Good day collegues.
I developed an application based on sparkLauncher that run an executable jar where are 5 operations. Each operation depending on the specific variable.
I have a main hadoop cluster spark2.3.0-hadoop2.6.5. It works good on it.
Part of my working code:

```
 private void runSparkJob(String pathToJar, final LocalDate startDate, final LocalDate endDate) {
        if (executionInProgress.get()) {
            LOGGER.warn("Execution already in progress");
            return;
        }
        Process sparkProcess = null;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Create SparkLauncher. SparkHome: [{}]. JarPath: [{}].", sparkHome, vmJarPath);
            executionInProgress.set(true);
            sparkProcess = new SparkLauncher()
                    .setAppName(activeOperationProfile)
                    .setSparkHome(sparkHome) //sparkHome folder on main cluster
                    .setAppResource(pathToJar) // jar with 5 operation
                    .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS,
                            String.format("-Drunner.operation-profile=%1$s -Doperation.startDate=%2$s -Doperation.endDate=%3$s", activeOperationProfile, startDate,endDate))
                    .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "12G")
                    .redirectToLog(LOGGER.getName())
                    .setMaster("yarn")
                    .launch();

            sparkProcess.waitFor();
            int exitCode = sparkProcess.exitValue();
            if (exitCode != 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Illegal exit code. Expected: [0]. Actual: [" + exitCode + "]");
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while running SparkApplication.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (sparkProcess != null && sparkProcess.isAlive()) {
                LOGGER.warn("Process still alive. Try to kill");
                sparkProcess.destroy();
            }
            executionInProgress.set(false);
        }
    }
```

I have started a docker container, where is a downloaded spark 2.3.0-hadoop6. This container needed for testers. **I changed master to .setMaster("local"), put new profile with paths to sparkHome, jarsWithOpertations** and packaged jar without shade(tried with shade and it doesn't work for me). When i tried to run my sparkLaunch app i have an exception now:

> 2018-08-06 14:47:53,150 INFO 
>   [n.m.m.b.r.SparkBaseOperationsRunner.runSparkJob] 105 : Create
>   SparkLauncher. SparkHome:
>   [/opt/bigtv/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6]. JarPath:
>   [/opt/bigtv/bin/multirating-bigdata-operations-MASTER-SNAPSHOT.jar].
>   2018-08-06 14:47:54,905 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 : 2018-08-06
>   14:47:54 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop
>   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where
>   applicable 2018-08-06 14:47:57,042 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 : 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57 ERROR SpringApplication:842 - Application run failed
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,043 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :
>   **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver;)V**
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,043 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:70)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,043 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:139)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,044 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:75)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,044 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,044 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:547)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,044 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:517)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,045 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:496)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,045 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:464)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,045 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:446)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,046 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) 2018-08-06 14:47:57,046
>   INFO  [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:445)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,046 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) 2018-08-06 14:47:57,046
>   INFO  [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:442)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,046 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:330)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,047 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:212)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,047 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:195)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,047 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,047 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,048 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,048 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,048 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,048 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,049 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,049 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,049 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:358)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,049 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,050 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,050 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,050 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   net.mediascope.multirating.bigdata.operations.OperationRunner.main(OperationRunner.java:21)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,050 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57,050 INFO  [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,051 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,051 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57,051 INFO  [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,051 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,052 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,052 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,052 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57,052 INFO  [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,053 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,053 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57,053 INFO  [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,053 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,054 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,054 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,054 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57,054 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :       at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57,058 INFO  [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 :
>   2018-08-06 14:47:57 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook
>   called 2018-08-06 14:47:57,060 INFO 
>   [o.a.spark.launcher.OutputRedirector.redirect] 63 : 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory
>   /tmp/spark-55b54924-e628-43fe-9e43-ed34d7f35a8b 2018-08-06
>   14:47:57,151 INFO 
>   [o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logAutoConfigurationReport]
>   101 :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

In my project i have snake yaml 1.19 from spring 5.0 and no others dependicies.
I can not understand what the problem is, perhaps when I put it into docker container manual it was necessary to install something else besides the spark.

Pom from module with operations:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.mediascope</groupId>
            <artifactId>multirating-bigdata-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Data Base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>2.71</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <profiles>
                                <profile>${profile.active}</profile>
                            </profiles>
                            <executable>true</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>hadoop</id>
            <build>
                <!--Необходимо для адаптации Spring-Boot приложения под запуск через Spark-->
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <transformers>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.provides</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                                        </transformer>
                                    </transformers>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>I
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found solution.
Origin spark package has folder jars where is snakeyml 1.15, i changed it to 1.19 and all work now.

Comment: For my case the version is different. I checked the version on my uber jar and update the same version in jars folder.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, how did you change the version to 1.19, can you please share the pom file after changes.

Comment: To find which version is getting picked, look at the maven dependency tree. Use the comand `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` This command helped me with a similar NoSuchMethodError, although it was for different jar.

Comment: Experienced on 2023/3/9 in a non-Spark project, and the fix was updating to `org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33`

Answer (score 0):

I could fix by downgrading version of snakeyml to 1.33, Spark provided version as 2.0 and with 1.33 I get this fixed.